# XPath/CSS/Locators to select title radio button option using WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

Is there any code for below issues?                                          I am unable to write the correct XPath or CSS to select the title "MRS" for below code. I am using below code, but unable to execute it.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@value='MRS']")).click();

```
<div class="question-controls clearfix">
   <div class="question-group ">
        <label class="off">Mr</label>
        <input type="radio" name="title" value="MR" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">

        <label class="off">Mrs</label>
        <input type="radio" name="title" value="MRS" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">

        <label class="on">Miss</label>
        <input type="radio" name="title" value="MISS" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">

        <label class="off">Ms</label>
        <input type="radio" name="title" value="MS" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">

        <label class="off">Dr</label>
        <input type="radio" name="title" value="DR" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">    
        <label class="off">Rev</label>
        <input type="radio" name="title" value="REV" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">    
        <input type="text" maxlength="20" style="display:none" name="otherTitle" value="" placeholder="Other title:" id="otherTitle">
    </div>          
</div>
```

link for reference:

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/36421/35535

Comment: Am I crazy or is your "link for reference" a link to your question? We need a link to the page.

Comment: link for page is                                                      https://compare-int-01.underwriteme.co.uk/customer/first

Comment: - I see a login page with no radios.

Comment: Need to login to see that page and i am not allowed to  provide the login details

Comment: You probably won't get a good answer then, sorry.

Comment: anyways,Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[@class='question-group']/input[@type='radio'][@value='MRS']
```

If the above xpath doesn't work, please see if this element you are trying to find is inside any iframe, in such case switch to the frame first and then try selecting this radio button.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("iframexpath here")));
```

Comment: tried your code  and still geting error message. please note the element is not in any iframe.     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='question-group']/input[@type='radio'][@value='MRS']")).click();

Comment: List<WebElement> radioList =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='question-group']/input[@type='radio']"));                                                                  
 for(int i=0;i<radioList.size();i++){        if(driver.radioList.getElement(i).getAttribute(value).equalsIgnoreCase("MRS")){ driver.getElement(i).click()} }   use the above code and let me know if it works please

Comment: i used above code but i am unable to execute the code due to radioList in if loop. message is  radioList cannot be resolved or is not in field.                      used below code                                           List<WebElement>radioList =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='question-group']/input[@type='radio']")); 
  for(int i=0;i<radioList.size();i++)
 
  {
   if(driver.radioList.getElement(i).getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase("MRS"))
   {
   driver.findElement(i).click();
   } }

Comment: sorry there is a correction, List<WebElement>radioList =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='question-group']/input[@type='radio']")); for(int i=0;i<radioList.size();i++) { if(radioList.getElement(i).getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase("MRS")) { radioList.getElement(i).click(); } }  remove the driver. from if{} it will wrok

Comment: unable to execute due ti getElement in if loop.   Message when i click on it :                                                                     the method getElement(int) is undefined for the type List<WebElement. it is telling me to add cast to radiolist

Comment: use get(i) instead of getElement()

Comment: one last error in            driver.findElement(i).click(); } }                                             error message is : The method findElement(By) in the type WebDriver is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: replace driver.findElement().click() with radioList.get(i).click();

Comment: Tried below code and it is unable to select the title MRS            List<WebElement>radioList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='question-group']/input[@type='radio']")); 
  for(int i=0;i<radioList.size();i++)
 
  {
   if(radioList.get(i).getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase("MRS"))
   {
    radioList.get(i).click();
    } }

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have provided to invoke `click()` on the element related to the title **MRS** as the element is having the `clearfix` class, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='question-controls clearfix']/div[@class='question-group']//label[contains(.,'Mrs')]//following::input[1]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Can you update the main question with the exact _error trace logs_ for further analysis?